# About the definition of $A^{e}-$mudule structure of an $A$-bimudule $M$

Tags: homological-algebra, noncommutative-geometry, hochschild-cohomology

Let $R$ be a conmutative ring (with unit $1$) and $A$ an associative $R$-algebra (with unit $1_{A}$). Let $A^{e}=A\otimes_{R}A^{opp}$ the eveloping algebra of $A$. Let $M$ be an $A$-bimodule. I want to prove that the following operation is a well defined structure of left $A^{e}$-module over $M$:

$$(a\otimes b)\cdot x=axb$$

for all $a,b\in A$ and $x\in M$. How can I make a rigorous proof?

Comment: It would be good if you listed the left $A^e$-module axioms for $M$, and then checked them. Are you stuck checking any of them? Also note that $axb$ is unambiguously defined because $M$ is an $A$-bimodule: part of the definition requires that $a(xb) = (ax)b$!

Comment: @PedroTamaroff How do you proof that $((a\otimes b)+(c\otimes d))\cdot x=(a\otimes b)\cdot x+(c\otimes d)\cdot x$ for all $a,b,c,d\in A$ and $x\in M$ ? On the other hand, it suppose that $a\otimes b$ is a coset and then the definition of $(a\otimes b)\cdot x$ dependes on $a$ and $b$. On Michael Atiyah's book of Introduction to Commutative Algebra he claim that this kind of definition must be proof rigorously that is well defined

Answer (score 0):

A convenient way to prove it is to use these two:

1. For an $R$-algebra $A$, an $A$-module structure on am $R$-module $M$ is equivalent an map of $R$-algebras $A\to \text{End}_R(M)$
2. The universal property of tensor products- a map of $R$ modules $A\otimes_RB \to N$ is equivalent to an $R$-bilinear map $A\times B\to N$

Combining these you can show it defines a $R$-bilinear map $A\times A^\text{op} \to End(M)$ to get well-definedness of $A^e \to End(M)$ then check its multiplicative

Comment: this is a correct answer